# Can I use in Spring the Message Resource Bundle when calling a JSP directly

Tags: spring, jsp, localization, spring-security, resourcebundle

I am using Spring 3.0 and working with the spring security for login. I have placed the login.jsp page in the webapp folder and I am trying to use messages for localization support e.g.:

```
<spring:message code="label.title"/>
```

Unfortunately, the jsp cannot find the message giving error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.title' for locale 'en_US'

When I use the message code in a jsp that goes through a controller, it works fine.

Since the spring security redirects to the login.jsp page when user is not logged in, the page is processed without a controller (directly).

Anyone knows how to make the jsp see the resource bundle also when not going through a controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to force Spring to render the page login.jsp, which is actually not managed by Spring. So, create a dummy controller:

```
/**
 * UI Controller that renders the signin-form.
 */
@Controller
public class SigninController {

    /**
     * Render the signin form to the person as HTML in their web browser.
     * Returns void and relies in request-to-view-name translation to kick-in to
     * resolve the view template to render.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void login() {
    }
}
```

and create the view named "login" depending of your used ViewResolver (TilesViewResolver, UrlBasedViewResolver...)

Comment: I did this and it worked. I just find it annoying that spring forces you to develop dummy code. Why can't the jsp tags just do it? Would seem simple. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you aren't using a controller, you're not using Spring MVC. Therefore, the spring JSP tags don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

and then refer the content directly in jsp as

```
<spring:message code="lable.name" />
```

Comment: That's what I have been doing. But it does not seem to find the messages. My guess is that because it goes directly to the jsp and not through the controller, the messages are not loaded.