# How to access resource bundle in login page of spring application using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to use resource bundle in login page
using tag `<spring:message code="login.name" />` but i am getting error as

```
No message found under code 'login.name' for locale 'en_US'.
```

I have referred this answer below ,but it is not working for me.
[Can I use in Spring the Message Resource Bundle when calling a JSP directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448237/can-i-use-in-spring-the-message-resource-bundle-when-calling-a-jsp-directly)

This is a sample snipped from my spring security.xml

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <sec:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
    <sec:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
    <sec:http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none"/>
    <!-- <sec:http pattern="/app/addNewUser.json" security="none"/> -->
    <sec:http pattern="/login.jsp" security="none"/>
    <sec:http use-expressions="true">

        <!--
             Allow all other requests. In a real application you should
             adopt a whitelisting approach where access is not allowed by default
          -->
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:form-login login-page='/login.jsp'
          authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"
          default-target-url="/index.jsp" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <sec:remember-me />
```

Any suggestion ?
Its my perception that login request should be routed via controller then I will be able to access the resource bundle but how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your login.jsp under WEB-INF directory.